# keep collapsible div open when the focus is set to any of its input triggers

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 3 input boxes that trigger the same div that is collapsible

```
<td>
  <input
    type="text" name="tbtext1" style="width: 90%;
    "data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exampleModal"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="exampleModal" />
</td>
<td style="width:20%">
  <input type="text" name="tbtext1" style=" width: 85%; position: relative; right: 0.9rem; "
                                                   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exampleModal" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="exampleModal" />
</td>
<td style="width:20%">
  <input type="text" name="tbtext1" style="width: 78%; position: relative; right: 2.3rem;"
                                                   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exampleModal" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="exampleModal" /><span style="position: relative; right: 1.2rem; ">= $</span>
</td>
<td style="width:20%">
  <input type="text" name="tbtext1" style="width: 99%; position: relative; right: 0.8rem; " />
</td>
<div class="collapse" id="exampleModal">
<div class="collapse" id="exampleModal">

<div class="row" style="margin-top:1rem">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Calc phys% using effective age of
            <input type="text" id="phys" style="width:3rem" />/Lifespan of <input type="text" id="phys" style="width:3rem" />
        </h5>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
<table class="innerModalTable" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; border-top: none; margin-left: -1.7rem;">
<tr>
    <th class="borderTd " style="text-align:center;border-top:none;border-left:none">&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="borderTd " style="text-align: left; width: 9.3rem; border-top: none; position: relative; left: 2rem;">Physical</th>
    <th class="borderTd " style="text-align: center; border-top: none; width: 9rem;">External</th>
    <th class="borderTd " style="text-align: center; border-top: none; border-right: none; width: 8rem;">Functional</th>
                                                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="borderTd ">% of Cost New</td>
    <td class="borderTd "><input type="text" style="width:100%" class="noBorderInputFocusOutline" /></td>
    <td class="borderTd "><input type="text" style="width: 100%" class="noBorderInputFocusOutline" /></td>
    <td class="borderTd "><input type="text" style="width: 100%" class="noBorderInputFocusOutline" /></td>
                                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="borderTd " style="width: 10.3rem; text-align: left;">Lump Sum</td>
    <td class="borderTd "><input type="text" style="width: 100%" class="noBorderInputFocusOutline" /></td>
    <td class="borderTd "><input type="text" style="width: 100%" class="noBorderInputFocusOutline" /></td>
    <td class="borderTd "><input type="text" style="width: 100%" class="noBorderInputFocusOutline" /></td>
                                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 </div>
```

currently its working like this when I click into any into any of the input feild the div toggles (collapses)
I want it to work such that when I focus on any of the input fields the div is opened and when I focus out of it the div is closed

Comment: i think instead of doing it with JS you should look into the `focus-within` css pseudo-class selector. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution to it using JQuery to achieve this task

```
 $(function () {
            console.log('ready')
            $('.toggleDepDiv').on('focus', function () {
                var x = document.activeElement.classList;
                if (x.contains("toggleDepDiv")) {
                    $('#exampleModal').collapse('show');
                }
            });


           
            $('.toggleDepDiv').focusout(function (e) {
                if (!e.relatedTarget.classList.contains('toggleDepDiv')) {
                    $('#exampleModal').collapse('hide');
                }
            });
        });
```

Basically, I collapsed and uncollapse it using focus and focusout event

I wasn't able to catch the active class using

```
var x = document.activeElement.classList;
```

So I used relatedTarget

```
if (!e.relatedTarget.classList.contains('toggleDepDiv'))
```

on focus out event